# efficiency of python sleep function to pause the script and set a raspi pin HIGH

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sleep

(some hardware part is coming here. but please check the software side )
I am continuously measuring some parameters using raspberry pi. I am using python. When the measured value is higher than a particular value, I want to set a GPIO pin high (for some LED indicator) and the measurement should be paused for next 10 seconds. I used time.sleep(10) function. after 10 seconds, measurement should continue. i noticed that even after 10 seconds, the PIN keeps HIGH Level (add the measured value was almost 10 times than the actual value. so i guess during sleep time, the values were adding up!! How). When I removed the time.sleep(10), everything works fine!!! I am using pigpio module. any suggestions please

```
newMeasurement=[]
lastMeasurement=[]
while True:
            mesurement = []
            time.sleep(1.0)
#pin 18 to control LED
            pi.write(18,0)


            for i in range(4):
                newMeasurement[i] = cb[i].tally()  # function to do measurement               
                mesurement.append(newMeasurement[i]-lastMeasurement[i])
                lastMeasurement[i]= newMeasurement[i]


            if (mesurement[0] > 100 or mesurement[1] > 110 or mesurement[2] > 120 or mesurement[3] >130 ):
                pi.write(18,1)                                           
                print("ON LED")
                time.sleep(10.0)  # sleep function
                pi.write(18,0)    #set LED back to LOW. It doesn't work!!!
            else:
                pi.write(18,0)
                print("LED OFF")
```

Comment: you need a regulated sleep, by measuring the time taken by other operations and subtract from the sleep time

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what confusing here is why my measured value was almost 10 times than the actual value after sleep period? it somehow means that script was running during sleep period!!!